# What is third-party dll?

Tags: c#, dll

I'm familiar with what `DLL` is, but lately I've been reading about `third-party DLLs`. Could  someone closely explain to me what actually does that stands for. What I've been reading so far didn't get me a clear picture of what it is?

For example, if I'm programming in C#, how can I call(use, do, assign, ...) them?

Comment: It's usually a DLL that you don't own the source code. You may have received it from a contractor, as a driver for a device or got it on the internet, provided by someone. These days, most of .NET third-party libs/DLLs are published as NuGet packages. If it's a CLR DLL, you may simply `Add reference`, point to it, set `using the.dll.namespace;` and go for it. If it's a COM DLL, then things will get a little more difficult.

Comment: This sounds like a question that belongs at english.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A third-party is an organisation that is not your, nor the client. Third party DLLs are libraries created by other organisation outside of yours.

You can use these third party DLLs by putting them into a folder in your solution and then creating a reference to it (Project-> Right Click-> Add Reference).

Once you have the DLL, that DLL will have a namespace. Add a "Using" statement at the top of your C# file with that namespace and you will be able to access the classes inside the DLL.

Comment: Also of note is that a lot of third-party .NET libraries are available through [NuGet](http://nuget.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the previous answer it is probably worth mentioning, that "dll's" from third-parties often come with documentation, providing information on how to use that specific API.